# InkScape - How to make this image standout

Tags: inkscape

[image]

Above is a snapshot of the `startup menu of Windows 10`. The top image on this screenshot is a logo that I created using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/). It is a math expression (square root of x). As you may have noticed the white foreground of this image is sort of blurred (dimmed). **Question**: How can we make the white color in this image (a math expression) to standout (like the image of "3D Viewer" in the same screenshot).

I tried the following in InkScape but it did not make any difference: `Extensions>Color>Brighter`

**Remark**: I do not have Adobe suite (photoshop or Illustrator).

In InkScape, I had to export the image from `svg` to `png` since start menu of Windows 10 does not accept svg.

**png image exported from the svg shown below**: This image is used in the above screen shot.

[image]

**Svg of the image**: As you may know the images in InkScape are transparent by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:ns2="http://www.iki.fi/pav/software/textext/"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   sodipodi:docname="LogoInkScapeSVG3.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="400"
     inkscape:cy="560"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1267"
     inkscape:window-height="728"
     inkscape:window-x="26"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <g
       transform="matrix(1.2065711,0,0,1.4112099,2.1965475,3.9863528)"
       ns2:version="1.3.1"
       ns2:texconverter="pdflatex"
       ns2:pdfconverter="inkscape"
       ns2:text="\\[\\sqrt{x}\\]"
       ns2:preamble="C:\Users\RazLT3user\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\extensions\textext\default_packages.tex"
       ns2:scale="1.0"
       ns2:alignment="middle center"
       ns2:jacobian_sqrt="0.352778"
       id="g33"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="96"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="96">
      <defs
         id="id-31589271-5255-4392-a85c-b26eb1abc946">
        <g
           id="id-84aa388d-f80b-4bde-9953-ad357cce4b71">
          <symbol
             overflow="visible"
             id="id-11b19bb8-a7fb-4ad0-b5a6-d07cf514da6f">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d=""
               id="id-438aae74-beb5-4047-8f5e-b8c13ef79c74" />
          </symbol>
          <symbol
             overflow="visible"
             id="id-36872d15-99fd-4586-aec8-364c924326e3">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d="m 3.875,8.515625 -1.75,-3.875 C 2.046875,4.484375 2,4.484375 1.96875,4.484375 c 0,0 -0.0625,0 -0.171875,0.078125 l -0.9375,0.71875 c -0.125,0.109375 -0.125,0.125 -0.125,0.15625 0,0.0625 0.015625,0.109375 0.09375,0.109375 0.0625,0 0.234375,-0.140625 0.34375,-0.21875 C 1.21875,5.28125 1.375,5.171875 1.484375,5.09375 l 1.96875,4.3125 C 3.515625,9.5625 3.5625,9.5625 3.65625,9.5625 c 0.15625,0 0.1875,-0.046875 0.25,-0.1875 L 8.4375,0 C 8.5,-0.140625 8.5,-0.171875 8.5,-0.203125 8.5,-0.296875 8.421875,-0.40625 8.296875,-0.40625 c -0.078125,0 -0.140625,0.0625 -0.21875,0.21875 z m 0,0"
               id="id-4d0b5927-ead0-4bcf-a90c-d5cdb66521b3" />
          </symbol>
          <symbol
             overflow="visible"
             id="id-6ff8466e-647f-4df8-a8ea-0a40d5dc5a98">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d=""
               id="id-01ef9785-e7d3-4e51-834d-fe63b628fef9" />
          </symbol>
          <symbol
             overflow="visible"
             id="id-92e64bbd-1d80-4b89-a9bc-ef54f6a6c644">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d="M 3.328125,-3.015625 C 3.390625,-3.265625 3.625,-4.1875 4.3125,-4.1875 c 0.046875,0 0.296875,0 0.5,0.125 C 4.53125,-4 4.34375,-3.765625 4.34375,-3.515625 c 0,0.15625 0.109375,0.34375 0.375,0.34375 0.21875,0 0.53125,-0.171875 0.53125,-0.578125 0,-0.515625 -0.578125,-0.65625 -0.921875,-0.65625 -0.578125,0 -0.921875,0.53125 -1.046875,0.75 -0.25,-0.65625 -0.78125,-0.75 -1.078125,-0.75 -1.03125,0 -1.609375,1.28125 -1.609375,1.53125 0,0.109375 0.109375,0.109375 0.125,0.109375 0.078125,0 0.109375,-0.03125 0.125,-0.109375 0.34375,-1.0625 1,-1.3125 1.34375,-1.3125 0.1875,0 0.53125,0.09375 0.53125,0.671875 0,0.3125 -0.171875,0.96875 -0.53125,2.375 -0.15625,0.609375 -0.515625,1.03125 -0.953125,1.03125 -0.0625,0 -0.28125,0 -0.5,-0.125 0.25,-0.0625 0.46875,-0.265625 0.46875,-0.546875 0,-0.265625 -0.21875,-0.34375 -0.359375,-0.34375 -0.3125,0 -0.546875,0.25 -0.546875,0.578125 0,0.453125 0.484375,0.65625 0.921875,0.65625 0.671875,0 1.03125,-0.703125 1.046875,-0.75 0.125,0.359375 0.484375,0.75 1.078125,0.75 1.03125,0 1.59375,-1.28125 1.59375,-1.53125 0,-0.109375 -0.078125,-0.109375 -0.109375,-0.109375 -0.09375,0 -0.109375,0.046875 -0.140625,0.109375 -0.328125,1.078125 -1,1.3125 -1.3125,1.3125 -0.390625,0 -0.546875,-0.3125 -0.546875,-0.65625 0,-0.21875 0.046875,-0.4375 0.15625,-0.875 z m 0,0"
               id="id-458118e1-e2bf-4d98-b13d-c3221d47a2c3" />
          </symbol>
        </g>
      </defs>
      <g
         id="id-f6eb776c-5b8b-4331-afec-1a727acba93c"
         transform="translate(-299.36,-138.652)">
        <g
           style="fill:#0a0a0a;fill-opacity:1"
           id="id-cf2a2197-13f3-4351-8504-42f4ab7e5b9a">
          <g
             transform="translate(298.626,139.058)"
             id="g24">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d="m 3.875,8.515625 -1.75,-3.875 C 2.046875,4.484375 2,4.484375 1.96875,4.484375 c 0,0 -0.0625,0 -0.171875,0.078125 l -0.9375,0.71875 c -0.125,0.109375 -0.125,0.125 -0.125,0.15625 0,0.0625 0.015625,0.109375 0.09375,0.109375 0.0625,0 0.234375,-0.140625 0.34375,-0.21875 C 1.21875,5.28125 1.375,5.171875 1.484375,5.09375 l 1.96875,4.3125 C 3.515625,9.5625 3.5625,9.5625 3.65625,9.5625 c 0.15625,0 0.1875,-0.046875 0.25,-0.1875 L 8.4375,0 C 8.5,-0.140625 8.5,-0.171875 8.5,-0.203125 8.5,-0.296875 8.421875,-0.40625 8.296875,-0.40625 c -0.078125,0 -0.140625,0.0625 -0.21875,0.21875 z m 0,0"
               id="id-471f70c2-8500-4d65-844f-53cc8ed642c9" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <path
           style="fill:none;stroke:#0a0a0a;stroke-width:0.398;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-opacity:1"
           d="M 0.0016875,-0.001375 H 5.693094"
           transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,306.928,138.858)"
           id="id-8c305f80-376d-46d6-b0fd-4187cba0383d" />
        <g
           style="fill:#0a0a0a;fill-opacity:1"
           id="id-cca5cbf8-89f9-405e-b28a-9505e5cf1131">
          <g
             transform="translate(306.928,146.72)"
             id="g29">
            <path
               style="stroke:none;stroke-width:0"
               d="M 3.328125,-3.015625 C 3.390625,-3.265625 3.625,-4.1875 4.3125,-4.1875 c 0.046875,0 0.296875,0 0.5,0.125 C 4.53125,-4 4.34375,-3.765625 4.34375,-3.515625 c 0,0.15625 0.109375,0.34375 0.375,0.34375 0.21875,0 0.53125,-0.171875 0.53125,-0.578125 0,-0.515625 -0.578125,-0.65625 -0.921875,-0.65625 -0.578125,0 -0.921875,0.53125 -1.046875,0.75 -0.25,-0.65625 -0.78125,-0.75 -1.078125,-0.75 -1.03125,0 -1.609375,1.28125 -1.609375,1.53125 0,0.109375 0.109375,0.109375 0.125,0.109375 0.078125,0 0.109375,-0.03125 0.125,-0.109375 0.34375,-1.0625 1,-1.3125 1.34375,-1.3125 0.1875,0 0.53125,0.09375 0.53125,0.671875 0,0.3125 -0.171875,0.96875 -0.53125,2.375 -0.15625,0.609375 -0.515625,1.03125 -0.953125,1.03125 -0.0625,0 -0.28125,0 -0.5,-0.125 0.25,-0.0625 0.46875,-0.265625 0.46875,-0.546875 0,-0.265625 -0.21875,-0.34375 -0.359375,-0.34375 -0.3125,0 -0.546875,0.25 -0.546875,0.578125 0,0.453125 0.484375,0.65625 0.921875,0.65625 0.671875,0 1.03125,-0.703125 1.046875,-0.75 0.125,0.359375 0.484375,0.75 1.078125,0.75 1.03125,0 1.59375,-1.28125 1.59375,-1.53125 0,-0.109375 -0.078125,-0.109375 -0.109375,-0.109375 -0.09375,0 -0.109375,0.046875 -0.140625,0.109375 -0.328125,1.078125 -1,1.3125 -1.3125,1.3125 -0.390625,0 -0.546875,-0.3125 -0.546875,-0.65625 0,-0.21875 0.046875,-0.4375 0.15625,-0.875 z m 0,0"
               id="id-60c6cf84-6794-405e-bece-08b2809dbdb7" />
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a slight stroke to thicken up the lines.

Here's an example. I added a 0.2 black stroke to everything. Perhaps a little heavier would still work well, but don't go crazy.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="16.2mm" height="14.2mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16.2 14.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="m8.98.467-5.09 12.2-2.11-5.46c-.0943-.22-.151-.22-.188-.22 0 0-.0758-.00018-.208.11l-1.13 1.01c-.151.154-.151.176-.151.22 0 .0878.0189.154.113.154.0755 0 .284-.198.416-.308.0567-.0659.246-.22.379-.33l2.38 6.06c.0755.22.132.22.246.22.189 0 .226-.0659.302-.264l5.49-13.2h6.7v-.559h-6.81c-.225.000199-.273.221-.339.367zm2.94 4.83c-1.25 0-1.95 1.8-1.95 2.15 0 .154.132.154.151.154.0943 0 .132-.044.151-.154.416-1.5 1.21-1.85 1.62-1.85.227 0 .641.132.641.944 0 .44-.208 1.36-.641 3.35-.189.857-.623 1.45-1.15 1.45-.0755 0-.339.000184-.604-.176.302-.0878.567-.374.567-.77 0-.374-.264-.483-.435-.483-.379 0-.66.351-.66.812 0 .638.586.923 1.11.923.811 0 1.25-.989 1.27-1.05.151.506.586 1.05 1.3 1.05 1.25 0 1.93-1.8 1.93-2.15 0-.154-.0943-.154-.132-.154-.113 0-.132.0662-.17.154-.397 1.52-1.21 1.85-1.58 1.85-.472 0-.66-.44-.66-.923 0-.308.0567-.614.189-1.23l.416-1.93c.0755-.351.36-1.65 1.19-1.65.0567 0 .358.000343.604.176-.339.0878-.567.417-.567.77 0 .22.132.483.453.483.264 0 .641-.242.641-.812 0-.725-.7-.923-1.12-.923-.7 0-1.11.746-1.26 1.05-.302-.923-.943-1.05-1.3-1.05z" fill="#0a0a0a" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".2"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: It worked great. Thank you for helping. I do agree with you that in terms of making it heavier we may not want to go crazy. Actually I may have to make it a touch less heavier since it looks a bit heavier than, for example, the "3d Viewer" in the screenshot of my post above. I'll test and see how it looks by making it a bit less heavier. I wish I had posted this question  two days earlier so you could have saved me a lot of time that I spent on this for two days to no avail. Graphic designing is not my cup of tea.

Comment: @nam No problem, glad it worked for you.  This problem is something that's quite common in graphic design, for example when you have a logo/icon which is going to be viewed at a small size. Small details/thin lines often fade or even completely disappear, so you have to be aware of that when you are designing something and always be mindful of the fact that this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Covert it to Windows enhanced metafile with some available free online file converters, like this https://convertio.co/svg-emf/

I guess Microsoft accepts at least its own vector format and renders it optimally to the display pixel grid.

Another guess: use a font which contains your symbol. I'm afraid Windows doesn't have such font and customizing system fonts to make a proprietary application visible as right in the system menu is quite a complex.

No guarantee, because I know nothing of Windows programming.

Comment: Inkscape can export to "EMF" format.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you for sharing your thoughts. As `@s.ouchene` mentioned, using `InkScape`, we actually can export `svg` to `EMF` format. But unfortunately the Windows programming I am using does not accept `.emf` file type. It does accept, `.ai`, `.png`, `.jpeg`, `.tiff`, `.tif`, `.bmp`